# Input tel phone number validation pattern

Tags: html, validation, input

I'm looking for the correct pattern for phone number validation by html5,
In Egypt, all phone numbers starts with (01) and then nine numbers like this: 
01123456789
I used this pattern to do this but it's not working right

```
<input type="text" name="phone" pattern="[01]{1}[0-9]{9}" title="Egypt Phone numbers">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if first two characters are static - 01

```
<input type="text" name="phone" pattern="01[0-9]{9}" title="Egypt Phone numbers">
```